# delphi change canvas pixel color

Tags: delphi, canvas

i need to convert all pixels of a canvas

found this function after a quick search in google

but dont work correct , but it seems must work good!!

```
function RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
var
  x, y : integer;
begin
  result := TBitmap.Create;
  result.width := OriginalBitmap.width;
  result.height := OriginalBitmap.height;

  for x := 1 to OriginalBitmap.width do
     for y := 1 to OriginalBitmap.height do
      begin
        result.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clBlack;
      end;

end;
```

this function dont make any change on the file

for example i used like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
imgf : TBitmap;
begin
if od1.Execute then
begin
  imgf := TBitmap.Create;
  imgf.LoadFromFile(od1.FileName);
  RGBBitmapTo1Bit(imgf);
  imgf.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(od1.FileName)+'test.bmp');
end;
```

but the output and input files are the same!!!

how can i assign a color to a pixel rightly!?

Comment: You can simplify the first function to this: `result:=TBitmap.Create;` `result.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;` `result.width := ..;` `result.height := ..;`. In effect all it does is create a bitmap and paint it to black, pixel by pixel. Not very efficient..

Comment: The second snippet: Your first function returns a bitmap. You don't use it.

Comment: yess, it must be `img33 := RGBBitmapTo1Bit(imgf);`

Comment: There are two small hints: 1) Use TBitmap.ScanLine instead of Canvas.Pixels - it works much faster 2) Use TBitmap.PixelFormat to set/obtain real size of the pixel data.

Comment: Or, you can do smething like this: `RGBBitmapTo1Bit(imgf).SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(od1.FileName)+'test.bmp');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has three problems with it:

1. Pixels are 0-indexed in both dimensions, so you need to change your loops accordingly.

   ```
   for x := 0 to OriginalBitmap.width-1 do
     for y := 0 to OriginalBitmap.height-1 do
   ```
2. your function DOES NOT modify the original `TBitmap`, it allocates and modifies a new `TBitmap` and then returns that to the caller, but the caller is ignoring that new bitmap, expecting the original `TBitmap` to have been modified instead.  You are saving the original `TBitmap` to file, which is why you don't see any of the pixels changed.
3. You are leaking memory for both `TBitmap` objects;

Try this instead:

```
function RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
var
  x, y : integer;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Width := OriginalBitmap.Width;
  Result.Height := OriginalBitmap.Height;

  for x := 0 to OriginalBitmap.Width-1 do
    for y := 0 to OriginalBitmap.Height-1 do
    begin
      Result.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clBlack;
    end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  imgf : TBitmap;
  imgf2 : TBitmap;
begin
  if od1.Execute then
  begin
    imgf := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      imgf.LoadFromFile(od1.FileName);
      imgf2 := RGBBitmapTo1Bit(imgf);
      try
        imgf2.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(od1.FileName)+'test.bmp');
      finally
        imgf2.Free;
      end;
    finally
      imgf.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Or this:

```
procedure RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap);
var
  x, y : integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to OriginalBitmap.Width-1 do
    for y := 0 to OriginalBitmap.Height-1 do
    begin
      OriginalBitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clBlack;
    end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  imgf : TBitmap;
begin
  if od1.Execute then
  begin
    imgf := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      imgf.LoadFromFile(od1.FileName);
      RGBBitmapTo1Bit(imgf);
      imgf.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(od1.FileName)+'test.bmp');
    finally
      imgf.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, `RGBBitmapTo1Bit()` is slow in both versions.  A faster version would be more like this:

```
function RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Width := OriginalBitmap.Width;
  Result.Height := OriginalBitmap.Height;
  Result.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Result.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height));
end;
```

```
function RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Result.Width := OriginalBitmap.Width;
  Result.Height := OriginalBitmap.Height;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap);
begin
  OriginalBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  OriginalBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, OriginalBitmap.Width, OriginalBitmap.Height));
end;
```

It also does not do what its name suggests - convert a bitmap to 1bit.  To do that, you have to set the `TBitmap.PixelFormat` property instead:

```
function RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
begin
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.PixelFormat := pf1Bit;
  Result.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Result.Width := OriginalBitmap.Width;
  Result.Height := OriginalBitmap.Height;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure RGBBitmapTo1Bit(OriginalBitmap : TBitmap);
begin
  OriginalBitmap.PixelFormat := pf1Bit;
  OriginalBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  OriginalBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, OriginalBitmap.Width, OriginalBitmap.Height));
end;
```

Comment: your all functions return a black colored image, yes?

Comment: Yes, because that is what the OP's original code was doing, so I made my examples do the same thing.

Comment: @peiman - Maybe you didn't refreshed the page in a while, OP removed the comment telling that it was just a sample and .. whatever. So, the question is all that's asked now.